# Jetpack Compose: Scaffold drawer opens when dragging MapView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mapview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

When using the drawer in a Jetpack Compose scaffold, gestures can be used to open and close it.
If the scaffold content contains a MapView, the map cannot be dragged around horizontally. Instead, the drawer is opened.

When scrollable rows are dragged (scrolled) through horizontally this does not happen, the drawer is not opened then.

**How can I prevent the drawer from opening when the map is dragged by the user?** When the rest of the scaffold content is dragged, the gesture should still work.

Unfortunately, wrapping the `AndroidView` with a `Row` does not solve the problem, as well as using the ModalDrawer instead of the scaffold.

---

Code to reproduce with Compose rc02 and kotlin 1.5.10 (EDIT: verified with Compose 1.0.3 and Kotlin 1.5.30):

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    drawerContent = {
                        Text("Drawer Content")
                    },
                    content = {
                        Column {
                            Text("Dragging here should open the drawer")

                            val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
                            AndroidView({ mapView }, Modifier.fillMaxSize())
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function `rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()` is taken from the [Crane sample app](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/4bc9d3ed17199ac79806bf2e4880ab790fac6362/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/details/MapViewUtils.kt#L36).

Answer (score 15):

Something similar happened to me when trying to integrate MapBox into an app with NavigationDrawer using Jetpack Compose.
What I did was add the property `drawerGesturesEnabled = false`, of the Scaffold, in this way the NavigationDrawer continues to work when I click on the menu Icon

If you use `drawerGesturesEnabled = scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen` you can close it normally

Comment: The `scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen` solution is what I am currently using. It seems to be the best we can do. What I actually want however, is some solution that allows to open the drawer with the dragging gesture - only disabled when dragging the map.

Comment: yeah, it makes sense, that's why official google maps app never had side bar opened by gesture

Comment: i have a problem with scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen solution as the compose is rebuild every time i open or close the drawer
is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Compose developers fixed the issue according to this ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202569585

Apparently the fix is not included in today's release 1.1.0-beta03, I guess we have to wait for the next one.